# javafx tableview update checkbox in column programmatically

Tags: checkbox, javafx, tableview

I am working in a desktop application with javafx.
In my screen, I have a tableview and in the first column, i have a checkbox, defined:

```
    markedColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().markedProperty());
    markedColumn.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(new Callback<Integer, ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(Integer param) {
            return data.get(param).markedProperty();
        }

    }));
```

Then, i filtered the tableview, for other field name:

```
    table.setItems(table.getItems().filtered(p -> p.getName().equals(name)));
```

but the marked column doesn't modify.

How can i modify the checkbox's state?

Thank you very much for your attention.

Regards.

Comment: What is `data` here? Since you're setting the table's items to another list (to which you don't actually keep a reference), you won't be getting the correct item when you call `data.get(param)`. It's pretty difficult to know for certain what is going wrong without a [MCVE], but it definitely looks like you are referencing the wrong list in your cell factory.

Comment: BTW: IMHO it's not a good idea to create a new `FilteredList` from the items for the sake removing unwanted items. By applying this multiple times you could a filtered list of the data in a filtered list of the data in another filtered list... (All those lists would be kept in memory.). The better approach would be: `table.getItems().removeIf(p -> !p.getName().equals(name));`

Comment: At the very minimum you should create a single filtered list and keep a reference to it. Then you can reset the filter as needed.

Comment: Thanks. I have the reference to initial list, Before filtering, i do: table.setItems(initialList); data is initialList.

Comment: The problem is this. In call method, i change initialList for table.getItems() and it works. Thanks.